# C# RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature, pycrypto

I've tried many times over to get C# and Python to sign the same the same way but have failed in all my attempts, is there something that I'm not doing correctly?

C#:

```
RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter formatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(key);
formatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
byte[] signature = formatter.CreateSignature(hash);
```

Python (using PyCrypto):

```
signature = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key).sign(SHA.new(message))
```

Comment: The padding is likely randomized. Does the signature change every time? If so, then you need to create a signature in one environment and verify it in the other in order to check compatibility.

Comment: Yes, it changes every time but it's not static data being signed it's randomized bytes and a timestamp.

Comment: What do you mean with `message = formatter.CreateSignature(hash);`. Shouldn't you be generating a *signature* from a *hashed message*?

Comment: @ArtjomB. PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for *signature generation* is not randomized by itself; it's fully deterministic. PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for encryption is though.

Comment: I am generating a signature from a hashed message. Both the C# version and the Python version need to generate a signature that's able to be communicated between the two languages and currently it doesn't.

Comment: The C# code works but the Python code doesn't, anyone have any idea what's up?

Comment: @JohnDong You seem to be hashing it yourself. Have you verified that the hashes in C# and Python are the same? (Please use @ replies if you expect somebody to receive a notification).

Comment: @ArtjomB. Both SHA-1 hashes are the same.

Comment: Have you tried to verify the signature that you generate in Python with C#?

Comment: @ArtjomB.Yes, the Python signature fails with the same data input.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I've noticed that the C# signature doesn't change even though the private key that signs it does because it has a random private exponent of 16 length. The python one, however, changes everytime that it's run.

Comment: That is strange. I don't have much experience with the signature generation in C#. Perhaps @MaartenBodewes has some idea.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the private key is a CRT private key for which the private exponent is simply ignored.

Comment: Note that the private exponent and/or CRT parameters are generated for a specific public/private key pair and modulus. You cannot simply replace the private exponent and expect to have a valid private key left.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes well the key is generated from rsa parameters and not from a pregenerated certificate, it encrypts the same way as C# but it doesn't sign the same way.

Comment: A private exponent should have a length comparable to the modulus length. A 16 byte private exponent should never happen. You are eorking outside of bounds.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes meant 0x80 sorry.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes any ideas? I've worked my butt off on this to find out the problem and I can't manage to find it so I'm pretty much out of luck.

Comment: What type is the `hash` variable in `CreateSignature`?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It's a raw SHA1 digest in the form of a byte array.

Comment: Shouldn't that be either a digest object or the data itself instead of the hash *over* the data?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes when you sign you're signing the hash of the data and not the data itself.

Comment: True butin general the hashing is *part of* the signature generation. Did you *try*?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes hash is the SHA1CryptoServiceProvider digest it's 20 bytes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105605/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-john-dong).